# react-moment fromnow ago function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In React i have React-moment library where i get output like this many sec's ago or min's ago etc from now.

```
<Moment fromNow ago>2018-09-04T18:30:00.000Z</Moment> // output <time>15 days ago</time>
```

I want to know is there any similar library like the above in javascript . I have tried moment.js library which has `fromnow` function in it.

```
var moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment(["2018-09-04T18:30:00.000Z"]).fromNow())
```

For which i got response as '9 Months ago'.

when i changed the format `console.log(moment([2018, 09, 04]).fromNow())` it is showing 14 days.

Does `moment.js` accepts only timestamp like this `[2018, 09, 04]`. Can't i pass like this `"2018-09-04T18:30:00.000Z"`. Because i dont want to do any operations on my Date.

Am i missing something ? 
Is there any library which supports My use case in JS.

Thanks

Comment: You can pass any format to a moment Date. But sometimes for some format, you need to specify the format for moment, so that moment knows how to handle your format. see here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse a [date string](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) (without the square brackets) for moment.js. Also (if you didn't know) [React-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment) uses moment.js. Here is a working example:

```js
console.log(moment("2018-09-04T18:30:00.000Z").fromNow())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Never thought `[ ]` brackets is causing the problem.